# Check condition normal subgroup in these three examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the subgroup H of G is a normal subgroup of G, for:
$$ i)\ G = S_5, \ H = \{id, (1,2)\} $$
$$ ii) \ G = (Sym(\mathbb{N}), \circ), \ H = \{f\in Sym(\mathbb{N}) : f(0) = 0 \}$$
$$ iii) \ G = S_4, \ H = \{id, (1,2,3), (1,3,2) \} $$

I know, that subgroup is normal, if:
$$ \forall g\in G \ \ gH = Hg  \ \ - \ \ \ H \lhd G $$

But I don't know how. Could you solve example number one and two?
Thanks for your help. I know that $$ S_5 = \{id, (1,2,3,4,5), ..., (5,4,3,2,1)\} \ \ \ \ 5! = 120  $$ but I don't understand it.

Comment: You are not just being asked to check if they are subgroups, which they all are. You are being asked to check if they are normal.

Comment: The conditions you cite are for checking if a subset is a subgroup. The exercise already tells you the subsets you are given are subgroups. What you do need to check is that the subgroups given are *normal*. This involves showing they are closed under conjugation, or not. Also, are you using one-line notation? If so, are you sure the statement of the exercise isn't using cycle notation instead?

Comment: $3)\ \forall g,h \ (g,h \in H \Rightarrow g*h\in H)$ or $3)\ \forall g,h \ (g \in G,h \in H \Rightarrow g*h\in H)$?

Comment: @eccstartup OP is clearly talking about the first one, as OP is clearly referencing the conditions for being closed under multiplication and inverses (i.e. being a subgroup). In fact the second condition you cite is not used for anything, because it would imply $H$ is the whole group or empty (a pointless condition). The condition for normality has to do with conjugation.

Comment: @eccstartup That would only ever hold for the entire group.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @anon

Comment: My fault, and already fixed, now contidion is ok :-) ?

Comment: Yes, the condition is now correct. Where are you stuck trying to apply it?

Comment: $gH = Hg$, means $\forall g \in G, \forall h_1 \in H, \exists h_2 \in H, gh_1=h_2g$.

Comment: @eccstartup And also the other direction.

Comment: Yes, but I never solved before example like this, so could you solve at least one example?

Comment: $\forall g \in G, gHg^{-1}=H$ ?

Comment: Yes, condition 1) and 2) are equivalent. $$ 1) \ \forall g \in G, \ gHg^{-1} = H \ \ 2) \ up $$

Comment: Look for $g$ in $G$, $x$ in $H$ such that $g^{-1}xg$ is not in $H$. If you find any such, you have proved $H$ is not normal in $G$. If you can prove there aren't any such, you have proved that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Mat, given the original version of your question it seems you are unclear about how to determine whether the given $H$ is even a subgroup of $G$, let alone a normal subgroup. Of course, it is already given in the question that these are subgroups, but I would suggest you understand how to show this is true before moving on to the more advanced notion of a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\bullet\;\;\;(13)^{-1}(12)(13)=(13)(12)(13)=(23)\notin H \;(\text{Example given by quid})$$

$$\bullet\;\;\;\text{Take}\;\;f(n):=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;n=0\\{}\\2&,\;\;n=1\\{}\\1&,\;\;n=2\\{}\\{}n&,\;\;n\neq 0,1,2\end{cases}\;\;,\;\;g(n):=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;n=0\\{}\\{}0&,\;\;n= 1\\{}\\n&,\;\;n\neq0,1\end{cases}\implies $$

$${}$$
$$g^{-1}fg(0)=g^{-1}f(1)=g^{-1}(2)=2\neq0\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;f\in H\;\ldots$$

$${}$$

$$\bullet\;\;\;(14)^{-1}(123)(14)=(14)(123)(14)=(234)\notin H\;\ldots\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

Comment: Ok, thanks for you, because I understand example i) and iii). But I still don't understand ii), why you go in these way?

Comment: It's an example of an element in $\,H\,$ and one conjugate of it which is not in $\,H\,$ ...

Comment: Could you tell me more about H in examle ii)?. Because I don't understand $$ f(0) = 0 $$ what does it mean?

Comment: $\;H\;$ is the subgroup of all permutations on the naturals which have zero as a fixed point.

Answer (score -1):

While the condition for a subgroup being normal is correct, it is often not the most efficient or at least intuitive to check this via using it.

Multiplying by $g^{-1}$ you get equivalently $gHg^{-1} = H$ for all $g \in G$.

So, to get you started you could just calculate $ghg^{-1}$ for a couple of $g\in G$ and $h \in H$ and see if all the elements are actually in $H$.

If you just find one where this is not true, you are done, and can conclude the group is *not* normal.

If you do not seem to find such a counterexample you might start to suspect the subgroup is actually normal and then try to show that indeed for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ you have $ghg^{-1} \in H$. If you can show this you are also done and the group is a normal subgroup. Note: what I just said means $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ for all $g \in G$ (not equality). But this is yet another condition for a subgroup to be a normal subgroup.

Comment: Could you show me how I should solve first example?

Comment: Well, just do what I said :-) Take saome element in the group, say $g=(1,3)$. Its inverse is? Also $(1,3)$. So calculate $(1,3).(1,2).(1,3)$ Is this an element of $H$? No. So $H$ is not a normal subgroup. (But actually do the calculation, the result will be of the form $(x,y)$.)

Comment: Ok, but why you took (1, 3) - them haven't in S5, I guess.

Comment: What do you denote by S5? I assumed the permutations of 1,2,3,4,5; since you say it has 120 elements this seems even more clear. So (1,3) denotes the permutation 1 to 3, 3 to 1, and everything else fixed. Just like (1,2) is the one 1 to 2 , 2 to 1 and everything else fixed. At least that is what I assumed. If you mean something else please clarify.

Comment: So (13) means $$ {1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5\choose 3 \ 2 \ 1 \ 4 \ 5}$$ :) ?

Comment: Yes, you could also write it like this.