# Check normal group in five examples.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $ G $ be a group and $ H $ subgroup of $ G $. Is $ H $ normal?
$$ 1) \ G = (\mathbb{R}^4, +), \ H = \{(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x + 2y + 3z + 4t = 0 \}$$
$$ 2) \ G = S_4, \ H \ generated \ by \ cycle  \ (1,2,3)$$
$$ 3) \ G = S_4, \ H \ generated \ by \ cycle  \ (1,2,3,4)$$
$$ 4) \ G = S_5 \times S_5, \ H = S_5 \times {id} $$
$$ 5) \ G = S_{10} \times S_{10} \times S_{10}, \ H = S_{10} \times {id} \times S_{10}$$

Exists some quick method to check this? I must check condition $ \forall g \in G \ gHg^{-1} = H $ or $ gH = Hg $ but I have problem with these examples. For first example I wrote: $(a,b,c,d)H(a,b,c,d)^{-1} = \{a \cdot x \cdot a^{-1}, b \cdot y \cdot b^{-1}, c \cdot z \cdot c^{-1}, d \cdot t \cdot d^{-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ it's enough?

Comment: The first group is abelian hence... This looks much more like homework, show some more effort

Comment: In an abelian group all subgroups are normal. What have you tried for the rest?

Comment: What have you learned from the answers to your earlier, similar questions? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468977/check-condition-normal-subgroup-in-these-three-examples

Comment: As you can see, that first example is abelian group?

Comment: You also have to prove that $H$ is a subgroup (unless this is defiantly given - I cannot quite tell from the first line). For the first example, you have to tell us what $\{a⋅x⋅a^{−1},b⋅y⋅b^{−1},c⋅z⋅c^{−1},d⋅t⋅d^{−1})\}$ as actually *is*. It turns out that it is in $H$, but you need to think a bit more about *why*. (Once you get to know a bit more you will hear the word abelian, and realise that this one is pretty easy!) Also, you might find this one slightly easier if you were to write it as $\{a+x-a,b+y-b,c+z-c,d+t-d)\}$

Comment: In particular, have you learned that all you have to check is that for all $g$ in $G$, for all $h$ in $H$, $g^{-1}hg$ is in $H$? This should make them all pretty easy. Put a little effort into it!

Comment: I guess that, two example isn't normal group, because in $ G $ I have, $ S_4 = \{{1 2 3 4 \choose 1 2 3 4}, {1 2 3 4 \choose 2 1 3 4 }, ... \} $, and in $ H = \{ {1 2 3 \choose 1 2 3}, {1 2 3 \choose 2 1 3}, ... \} $. I have right?

Comment: In part 1 you have to show that the resulting vector **is in the subset $H$.** It is trivially in $\mathbb{R}^4$. When viewes as an element of $S_4$ the cycle $(123)$ is in column notation the permutation $\pmatrix{1234\cr2314\cr}$. In other words the elements not in the cycle are considered to be mapped to themselves. Therefore you have more work to do in both those parts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what do you think about my post with $ S_4 $? I have right?

Comment: I think I already said that you are not. That subgroup $H$ has the elements $$\pmatrix{1234\cr1234\cr},\pmatrix{1234\cr2314\cr},\pmatrix{1234\cr3124\cr}.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen because we can write $ (1,2,3)(4) $, right? So $ {1 2 3 4 \choose 2 3 1 4} $ .

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: ok, but what can I see, that current example is normal group or not? Because I still don't see. And how i should prove that is normal group? I never proved it.

Comment: @Mat Consider the element $(1, 4)$, aka the following permutation: $$\pmatrix{1234\cr1231\cr}$$

Comment: @user1729 I must consider $ {1 2 3 4 \choose 4 2 3 1} $ with every element from $ H $, right?

Comment: @Mat Experiment!

Comment: (Also, I think you need to go and think about your questions. It is difficult to help you if there is a massive stream of comments with you asking for clarification all the time (and so I am voting to close this question). Sit down and think about, for example, Q3. Come back tomorrow *only* asking about that one, and with some very specific questions. And play around a bit with all of this stuff until you have a better feel for it! Study the definitions and don't worry so much about getting stuff wrong...)

Comment: Ok, $ {1 2 3 4 \choose 4 2 3 1} \circ {1 2 3 4 \choose 2 3 1 4} \circ {1 2 3 4 \choose 4 2 3 1} = {1 2 3 4 \choose 2 3 4 1} \circ {1 2 3 4 \choose 4 2 3 1} = {1 2 3 4 \choose 1 3 4 2} $ And this isn't in $ H $, Right? But could you write me, how you find this counterexample?

Comment: @Mat Yes, you're right, good! I found this counter-example because I have spent a lot of time thinking about group theory, so I have a feel for it. The only way to get such a feel is practice. (Also, this discussion is getting to long so I am leaving it now.)

Comment: How note, that $ 4) $ is abelian group?

Comment: @Mat: Did you get the answer?

Comment: @BabakS. what answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can just give you a simple way. You'd better reflect about [Don's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/469030/8581) again and again. We know that:

$$S_4=\{id, (3,4), (2,3), (2,3,4), (2,4,3), (2,4), (1,2), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3), 
  (1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,2), (1,3,4,2), (1,3), (1,3,4), 
  (1,3)(2,4), (1,3,2,4), (1,4,3,2), (1,4,2), (1,4,3), (1,4), (1,4,2,3), 
  (1,4)(2,3)\}$$ and $$H=\langle (1,2,3)\rangle=\{id, (1,2,3), (1,3,2)\}$$ Also, you may know that if $\sigma\in S_4$ and $(k_1,k_2,...,k_3)\in S_4$ then $$\sigma^{-1}(k_1,k_2,...,k_r)\sigma=(k_1\sigma,k_2\sigma,...,k_r\sigma)$$ Now, lets try the cycles in which for example $4$ is contained in $(k_1\sigma,k_2\sigma,...,k_r\sigma)$'s for $(k_1,k_2,...,k_r)\in H$ and some $\sigma\in S_4$. This is just a feeling to get a contradiction. Of course, we are walking on the way of showing the normality. Now, take $$\sigma=(3,4)\to \sigma^{-1}=(3,4)$$ and $$\sigma^{-1}(1,2,3)\sigma=(1,2,4)\notin H$$

Comment: Please tell me if I was wrong in any steps. I know this is an elementary approach and so I don't insist that this way is the best way and so it should be acceptable. I am here to learn more and more points and to fresh my little knowledge about Maths. Thanks.

Comment: Could you write me how you find counter-example?

Comment: @Mat: Just feeling. As user1729 commented in his last one, working with symmetric groups, especially $S_3, S_4$, gives us an insight and without doing exercises on them you cannot guess where to attack  the problem.

Comment: $\ddot\smile \quad +1 \quad$